# Visual studio 2012 step into jumps to wrong places

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have rebuild the projeact, even deleted .pdb and .idb files, but debugger jumps into wrong files and wrong functions when I press `F11` (step into) whereas `F10` works correctly. How to clear debug info or generate correct one?

Comment: What does "jumps into wrong files and wrong functions" actually mean? Any chance you can post a simple example?

Comment: Forget, it was jumping to wrong functions, because I was calling a function with default parameters which where evaluated with another function return values. Hence, there were "wrong" function calls :). Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone will have the same stupid situation I will explain my case: it was jumping to "wrong" functions, because I was calling a function with default parameters which where evaluated with another function return values. Hence, there were "wrong" function calls :). Sorry...